# Powershell: how to pause or delay or block shutdown to give time for cleanup tasks?

Tags: windows, powershell, shutdown, reboot

I have a powershell script that is running all the time on windows 7. If user does computer shutdown or reboot, I need a little time to do cleanup tasks such as updating log file.

Is there a way to delay shutdown from within script?

Solutions I've found from searching don't work well:
*Listening for events such as SessionEnding are too late and powershell is closed before script has time to do anything

*I'm looking for a solution within the script that runs at startup instead of separate solution such as adding a 2nd script to group policy that runs on shutdown

I've looked at WM_QUERYENDSESSION but I can't get it to work for powershell script.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is not to detect a shutdown but to change your script so that it is logging more frequently in order to reduce the data loss at shutdown? Perhaps the cleanup steps should run at startup, not shutdown?

Comment: Agree with gvee. On the other hand, I wrote a VB snippet some time ago and some others wrote similiar thinks in CS, both can be integrated in PoSh Scripts. Take a look at [this minimalistic sample](https://gist.github.com/Clijsters/d8d0eaeb2437c7cd61ac)

Comment: gvee:  data loss will always happen unless i set to unacceptable high update frequency. cleanup steps include updating log file with session data which means it can't be done at startup

Comment: Clijsters: thank you for reference to WM_QUERYENDSESSION, yes i've across it in searching but i cant get it to work with a powershell script

Answer (score 0):

Add the script on GPE on your local computer, So the script will run while shutdown.